# Tengo un problema al pasar el id por un button me coge toda la cadena del button en php

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo un problema al capturar el id me envía toda la cadena del button alguien podria saber cual es el error se lo agradecería.
adjunto los códigos
Controller

```
case "listar":
        $datos = $encabezado->get_encabezados($_POST["num_pe"]);
        $data = Array();
        foreach($datos as $row){
            $sub_array = array();
            $sub_array[]=$row["id_local"];
            $sub_array[]=$row["nombre_beneficiario"];
            $sub_array[]=$row["sexo_beneficiario"];
            $sub_array[]=$row["edad"];
            $sub_array[]=$row["id_comunicacion"];
            $sub_array[]=$row["plantilla"];
            $sub_array[]=$row["npreferido_apoyador"];
            $sub_array[]=$row["estatus"];
            $sub_array[]= '<button type="button" onclick="llenarcarta('.$row["id_comunicacion"].');" id="'.$row["id_comunicacion"].'" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div></button>';               
            $data[]=$sub_array;
        }
        $results = array(
            "sEcho"=>1,
            "iTotalRecords"=>count($data),
            "iTotalDisplayRecords"=>count($data),
            "aaData"=>$data);
        echo json_encode($results);
    
    break;
```

Index, donde trato de capturar el id

```
<script type="text/javascript"> function llenarcarta(id_comunicacion){
console.log(id_comunicacion);    
$("#modalcarta").modal('show');}</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poner funciones in-line es una mala práctica como haces aquí:

```
        $sub_array[]= '<button type="button" onclick="llenarcarta('.$row["id_comunicacion"].');" id="'.$row["id_comunicacion"].'" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div></button>';
```

Ahí estás poniendo una función in-line que es  `onclick`, eso hace que el contenido HTML sea siempre dependiente del código Javascript, dificultando el mantenimiento. Imagina una aplicación más o menos grande donde pones cientos o miles de funciones in-line en el HTML y se necesita pasar más parámetros a la función por ejemplo, tendrás que empezar a adivinar en qué contenidos HTML entre cientos o miles pusiste esa función para actualizar el código.

Por eso se recomienda lanzar las funciones escuchando los eventos.

Simplemente escribirías el botón así:

```
        $sub_array[]= "<button type=\"button\" id=\"$row[id_comunicacion]\" class=\"btn btn-outline-primary\"><div><i class=\"far fa-edit\"></i></div></button>";
```

Y en Javascript escuchas los clicks de ese botón mediante eventos. Otra ventaja de hacer esto es que si necesitas lanzar la misma función para varios tipos de elementos los puedes agrupar por selectores y agregar una función de escucha a todos juntos sin tener que ir poniendo en cada uno la función in-line. Si quieres escuchar cada elemento en particular entonces lo mejor es agregar una función de escucha por su id.

Aquí asumiremos que quieres escuchar los clicks de los botones con la clase `btn-outline-primary` (es sólo un ejemplo, lo puedes cambiar por lo que quieras). Asumiendo eso, el código quedaría así:

```
document.querySelectorAll('button.btn-outline-primary').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(item.id);
  })
})
```

Ahí estarás escuchando los clicks de **todos los botones que tengan la clase `btn-outline-primary`** y dentro de la escucha del evento podrás mostrar el id del botón que se presionó o cualquier otro atributo o propiedad del mismo.

Veamos un ejemplo funcional, aquí hay tres botones que son escuchados por su clase, prueba a hacer click en ellos y verás en cada caso su id. Y hay un botón que no es escuchado por tener una clase distinta.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('button.btn-outline-primary').forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(`id: ${item.id}, value: ${item.value}`);
  })
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="id1" value="v1" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>1</button>

<button type="button" id="id2" value="v2" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>2</button>

<button type="button" id="id3" value="v3" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>3</button>

<hr />
<!-- este no se incluye porque tiene otra clase -->
<button type="button" id="id4" value="v4" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>Este no</button>
```

En el caso de necesitar escuchar solamente un botón en particular, puedes agregar el listener por su id o de algún otro modo que lo identifique de forma unívoca.

En el siguiente ejemplo, la función de escucha se asigna solamente al primer botón, porque usamos su id para asignarla y el id es único.

```js
document.querySelector('#id1').addEventListener('click', event => {
    var currentBtn=event.currentTarget;
    console.log(`id: ${currentBtn.id}, value: ${currentBtn.value}`);
})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="id1" value="valor1" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>Sólo este</button>

<button type="button" id="id2" value="valor2" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>No</button>

<button type="button" id="id3" value="valor3" class="btn btn-outline-primary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>No</button>

<hr />
<!-- este no se incluye porque tiene otra clase -->
<button type="button" id="id4" value="valor4" class="btn btn-outline-secondary"><div><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>Este tampoco</button>
```

Como podrás comprender, la escucha de eventos no solamente ofrece las ventajas antes mencionadas, sino que puedes asignar varios tipos de escucha para un mismo elemento de forma diferenciada.

Imagina un contexto en el que necesites hacer algo en particular solamente cuando se haga click en el boton1, y también hacer otra cosa cuando se haga click en todos los botones de una determinada clase (incluido el boton1). Asignarías dos eventos de escucha, uno por id y otro por clase y dentro de cada listener lo que haya que hacer para el boton1 en particular y para los botones agrupados.

Otra cosa es que esto no está limitado solamente a los clicks, sino que puedes asignar listeners para cualquier evento como change, keypress, etc.

Comment: Gracias probaré la opción que mencionas.